# ionic3: build.gradle files

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, ionic3, build.gradle

Where do I find the build.gradle files on the project level and on the app/module level? In my ionic3 files, I find one build.gradle under platforms/android. Another one is in CordovaLib. I'm trying to install Google Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Use the gradle file platforms/android/app/app.gradle. Enter the Google Auth dependencies in this gradle file and rebuild the project from Android Studio.